# How to increase Http POST size in Jboss server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post, jboss

I am passing an array of values through POST method dynamically.
If i pass more than 50 array values, i am not able to process those data.
I am getting error 505.

I browsed and found that it is an Http error, which refers the post size is not good here.

So i added the properties in my jboss configuarion,

```
</system-properties>
<property name="org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters.MAX_COUNT" value="-1"/>
    </system-properties>
```

Even after this, i am not able to pass array value more than 50.

Please give some solution for this.

This is my code, in Restfull webservice, where i get data from angular controller.

```
this.updateConstraint = function($scope, $location, $routeParams) {
        var url = hostName + "/dcr/rest/capacityfile/searchcf/blockC/addSubFilesBlocC";
        var listSubFiles = $scope.capacityAddSubFile;
        var idCapacity = $routeParams.capacityFileId;
        var promise = $http({
            url : url,
            method : "POST",
            params :{ subFileCSF : $scope.capacityAddSubFile,
                      partConstraint : $scope.selectedPartNumberAndConstraint,
                      partConstraintAdd : $scope.selectedPartNumberAndConstraintAdd,
                capacityFileId : $routeParams.capacityFileId},

        }).success(function(data, status, headers) {

        }).error(function(data, status, headers) {
            // alert("Failed to access"+status+" "+headers);
        });
        return promise;
    };
```

Here the i am getting error, it is showing error 505.
Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `max-post-size` at connector level.

> /subsystem=web/connector=http:write-attribute(name=max-post-size, value=80)